# Get column x's Cells from a Range of Cells in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Range of Cells, let's say: Range("A1:D20") which is stored in a Range variable. In my case, the range is actually a named range.
E.g.

```
Set rngList = Range("LIST")
```

I'm trying to use a 'for each' loop to traverse only the Cells in column 2. EDIT: this is a relative reference, not absolute: 2nd column of the range.

E.g.

```
for each rngCell in rngList.Columns(2)
   //Do stuff
next
```

The .Columns(2) doesn't work. Is there a simple way to do this?

Cheers

Comment: To clarify: when I say 'cells in column 2', I'm talking about column 2 relative to the range of cells in the range object, not column 2 of the spreadsheet (i.e. absolute). In my example, column 2 is the same for both, but say it was Range("D1:G20"), 'column 2' would be column E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `.Cells` after `.Columns(2)`:

```vb
For Each rngCell In Range("LIST").Columns(2).Cells
   Debug.Print rngCell
Next
```

Comment: this way you're getting the cells in the 2nd column of the `Range("LIST") ` and not those _"in column 2"_ as per OP's request

Comment: @user3598756, The OP doesn't specify whether it's an absolute or a relative position. However the provided example targets a relative position. Moreover, the issue here is not about the targeted column, but who to iterate the cells within a column.

Comment: _"traverse only the Cells in column 2"_ sounds to me quite as an _absolute_ reference. The example is provided by a user who didn't know how to achieve the above quoted goal. And I can't understand your 3rd sentence  (_"Moreover..."_). Finally, the user could clarify his need, whether "absolute" or "relative" (though not relevant for a Range beginning from column "A")

Comment: Thanks Florent, I thought there was going to be a simple answer to this, and this is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create another range directly from your existing range using column B (efficient), or you could just check if each cell in your existing range is in column 2, before doing your stuff:

Method 1 (create a derivative range):

```
Sub method1()

    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim rngList2 As Range

    Set rngList = Range("LIST")

    Set rngList2 = Range("B" & rngList.Row, Range("B" & (rngList.Row + rngList.Rows.Count - 1)))

    For Each rngCell In rngList2
        rngCell.Value = "hey1"
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Method 2 (check if cell is in column 2):

```
Sub method2()

    Dim rngList As Range

    Set rngList = Range("LIST")

    For Each rngCell In rngList
        If rngCell.Column = 2 Then
            rngCell.Value = "hey2"
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
For Each rngCell In Intersect(rngList, rngList.Parent.Columns(2))
'   //Do stuff
Next
```